# About FIREBASE => Angular , How read data in FIREBASE when we use Push method to write data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem when i want to read firebase DATA i can't retrieve data:

1. First time i write data in firebase like that:

   ```
   saveJoueurPoule(poule: any,newJoueur: any){
     console.log("poule creation" + poule);
     firebase.database().ref('/poule1).push(newJoueur);
   }
   ```

   `newJoueur` is an object:

   ```
   export class Joueur {
       //   photo: string;
       constructor(public nom: string , 
              public prenom: string,
              public poule: number, 
              public point: number,
              public victoire: number ,               
              public defaite: number,
              public nbdejeu: number
       ){}
   ```

   Write data work nice:

   [image: Firebase Poule]
2. But When i want to read data firebase "Poule1" like this:

   ```
   firebase.database().ref('/poule1').on('value', (data) => {
       this.joueurClassement = data.val() ? data.val() : [] ;
       console.log( this.joueurClassement[0].nom);=> undifined
   ```

   My object `joueurClassement` is empty every time (i think).

But if i use a `set` methode to write => `firebase.database().ref('/joueurs').set(this.joueur);` my reading work very well why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you FRank for yout fast answer, it's better  but it doesn't work.

My CODE:

```
firebase.database().ref('/poule1').on('value', (data) => {
    data.forEach((child) => this.joueurClass = data.val())
    console.log("Non  = "  + this.joueurClass.nom )
    })
```

Console display  "Non  = undefined " so i think JoueurClass is empty.
May be , have to initialize a new Object joueurClass ?

an other question:
there are several data and for each child the result overwrite joueurClass , i would like in my object joueurClass all DAta , exemple:

```
joueurClass [{vital,arnaud,0,0,0,0,0},{frank,ldjldldld,0,0,0,0,0}]
```

i hope to be clear. thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you use `push()` you create a new unique node under the location where you call it. And that means that when you read the data, you must handle the fact that there can be multiple child nodes.

You're *trying* to do that in your code by the `[0]` in `this.joueurClassement[0]`, but if you look at your JSON there is no index `0`. Calling `push()` generates so-called push IDs, which are (for very good reasons partially explained [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)) **not** array indexes.

To deal with the extra level of child nodes with unknown keys, you can use Firebase's built-in `forEach` method:

```
firebase.database().ref('/poule1').on('value', (data) => {
    data.forEach((child) =>
        this.joueurClassement = data.val();
        console.log(this.joueurClassement.nom);
    })
})
```