# How do I handle unnamed nodes in my firebase realtime database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Database]
{
"chats": {
"3q7QDEHAVpU3DhiNyAOKlZY7L0S25rAQ6mD63HRiygVytCutjMfyZr43": {
"messages": {
"-MhP9vpwRKLND9tIBBOT": {
"message": "thanks",
"senderId": "5rAQ6mD63HRiygVytCutjMfyZr43",
"timeStamp": 1629305419888
},
"-MhSZ8z1kObr2W0UOdZK": {
"message": "hello",
"senderId": "3q7QDEHAVpU3DhiNyAOKlZY7L0S2",
"timeStamp": 1629362363332
},
}
},
"3q7QDEHAVpU3DhiNyAOKlZY7L0S2Ud9F8Ke4bZTMu9vMf5GF98jnwng2":
{},
"5rAQ6mD63HRiygVytCutjMfyZr433q7QDEHAVpU3DhiNyAOKlZY7L0S2":
{},
}
}

I want to retrieve data from the real time database but due to unnamed nodes I am not able to capture the data. Please help me?
When I run the function I getting null in console.log:

Path is correct but snapshot shown null in console:
snapshot: null

```html
function selectAllData6() {
    var Id1 = this.id;
    var Path1 =               firebase.database().ref("chats/{senderId}/messages/{receiverId}/message");
    Path1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    console.log("message: " + message);
    console.log("Path1: " + Path1);
    console.log("snapshot: " + snapshot.val());
    });
}
selectAllData6();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unnamed nodes"? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and indicate those nodes.

Comment: An educated guess is that you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172608

Comment: unnamed nodes are as shown cross marked in database image. actually I am new for firebase database, so I am getting problems. I much Thankful to you, please give me solution please.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.